# Django doesn't parse a custom http accept header

Tags: python, django, http, django-views, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to allow Django app to accept the custom accept header like "application/vdn.name.v1+json"?

I keep getting a response like this

```
Could not satisfy the request Accept header.
```

I am using Django Rest Framework as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try defining a [custom renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers) and setting the `media_type` attribute.

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class MyRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/vdn.name.v1+json'
```

Then enable your renderer (see [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers) for more info)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'path.to.MyRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to define multiple media_type like media_type=['application/vdn.name.v1+json','application/vdn.name.v2+json' ]?